# How to capture browser refresh event using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to  navigate to a particular page/start page of my application when user clicks on refresh button in any other page of my application.I need javascript function for this.Can anyone suggest the best possible way.
thanks.

The code i tried is

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
              if (evt) {
                  evt.stopPropagation();   
                  console.log("refreshed in appBootstrap");
                  console.log("current url is "+location.href)
                  window.location.href= "/scm/mgmt/case";
                  console.log("relocated")




                    }
               }
```

This does not redirect me to the intended page rather remains in the same page on refresh.I need to navigate to the specified url on page refresh each time.

Comment: SO is not a programming service, you should show everyone what have you tried, or you may also ask for conceptual programming advice on your problem

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
        if (evt) {
                  evt.stopPropagation();   
            console.log("refreshed in appBootstrap");
                  console.log("current url is "+location.href)
            window.location.href= "/scm/mgmt/case";
                 
                  console.log("relocated")
                  
                
                    
                    }
            }//This is not working it remains in the same page and does not get redirected to required page

Answer (score 2):

You can try a counter kind of thing. if counter is 2 than redirect to your required page.

or you can try `document.referrer` 
but some browser may not support this.